# Is there any performance impact by using interface as reference

Tags: c#, performance, interface, reference, abstract-class

Which is better in terms of performance:

1.)Reference to an object through base class's reference

```
abstract class BaseClass{}

class A : BaseClass{}
class B : BaseClass{}

static void Main(){
 BaseClass objectInstance = new A();
           objectInstance = new B();
}
```

or

2.) Reference to an object through an interfaces' reference:

```
 interface IBase{}

 class A : IBase{}
 class B : IBase{}

 static void Main(){
    IBase objectInstance = new A();
    objectInstance = new B();
}
```

Comment: This would be *super* easy for you to test yourself.  It probably took you more time to write up and format this question correctly than it would have to run a simple benchmark.

Comment: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: It has no consequence in this code, what matters is what you do next.  An interface method call does have some overhead, it has to go through a call stub and the jitter optimizer cannot inline the method.  The perf difference is hard to measure accurately, it is very fast code and pretty easy to fumble the benchmark by making the non-interface method completely disappear.  Interfaces are a structural design pattern, you neither opt-in to them nor arbitrarily throw them away just for the heck of it.  Very heavily micro-optimized by the CLR, they don't suck.

Answer (score 0):

The impact is microscopic and until you're writing really performance critical section of code, you may not pay attention and use whatever best suits your needs.

However, there is one case when you may run into performance trouble with interfaces. It happens when you have a method which accepts interface as a parameter and you have a struct which implements the interface.

```
class Demo {
    public static void Method(IInterface input) {};
}

struct Struct: IInterface {}


Demo.Method(new Struct(arg1, arg2))
```

Such code will cause boxing of struct. You should consider using generics with constraints to avoid boxing

```
class Demo {
    public static void Method<T>(T input) where T: IInterface {};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be time/speed performance issues but if youre working with small collections the difference is negligible.  If you use a list as a parameter use an iList instead..it's up to you.  Here is a reference...  https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/9105